# Simulink - electrical appliances and consumption

Tags: matlab, simulink, energy, consumption

I would like to ask you for idea or how to define (using Simulink blocks) an electrical appliance with their own power, and energy consumption in time. This block should be possible to switch on and off.

If anybody knows an example of something similar, please leave a link.

At the moment I have defined it with R block, then I calculate its power (kW) and multiply it by time in hours, but this is not good way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [SimPowerSystems](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simpower/) or [SimElectronics](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simelectronics/)?

Comment: Yes i have. I have already register at mathworks to see their interactive tutorials but im not realy found what i want. I just need an advice or example to see how something similar works, and then build something own.